# How to update with LINQ an object property knowing its name?

Tags: c#, linq

My problem is very simple : I am parsing an Excel file containing the name of the SQL column, and its value.

I would like, with LINQ, to create my object and set its property, knowing its name. How can I do it ? I would like to do something like :

```
object obj = new object();
obj["property_name"] = "test";
```

but instead I can only do something like obj.propertyName which doesn't suite my case.

Thank you.

Comment: Another useful life lesson "Don't sneer".

Comment: How you retrieve information from `Excel` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do this with Reflection...

```
obj.GetType( ).GetProperty( "property_name" ).SetValue( obj, "test" );
```

// EDIT:

sorry, i give you the wrong code-example. i have made an update.

Comment: I have to specify an index in the SetValue but I can't manage to get anything but "Object cannot be stored in an array of this type."

Answer (score 1):

You can use Anonymous Types 
Look -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx

```
var myObj  = new { property_name = "test"};
```